Azure B2C - Localisation custom policy issue
I am trying to localize RadioSingleSelect buttons on the selfAsserted.html page. This is where users will select their preferred MFA method. I managed to localize the header but I can't seem to change the language of the radio buttons. I can't find a specific StringID for these. I did try using the ElementType="UxElement" but still could not get the buttons converted. Please see below for snippets of B2C localisation policy, inspected code from the selfAsserted.html page and my extension attribute. Any suggestions or recommendations welcome! Thanks in advance.
Inspected code from the selfAsserted.html page:
<div class="attrEntry">
   <label for="extension_mfaMethod">Select your preferred MFA method</label>
   <div class="error itemLevel" aria-hidden="true">
      <p>Esta información es obligatoria.</p>
   </div>
   <input id="extension_mfaMethod_email" name="extension_mfaMethod" type="radio" value="email" checked=""><label for="extension_mfaMethod_email">Receive a code via Email</label>
   <input id="extension_mfaMethod_totp" name="extension_mfaMethod" type="radio" value="totp"><label for="extension_mfaMethod_totp">Use an Authenticator App</label>
   <input id="extension_mfaMethod_opt-out" name="extension_mfaMethod" type="radio" value="opt-out"><label for="extension_mfaMethod_opt-out">Opt out of Multi-Factor Authentication</label>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-help="" class="helpLink tiny">¿Qué es esto?</a>
</div>

B2C localisation policy:
<LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.es">
   <LocalizedStrings>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaMethod" StringId="DisplayName">TestTitle</LocalizedString> (THIS IS WORKING)
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaMethod_email" StringId="DisplayName">TestEmail</LocalizedString> (NOT WORKING)
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaMethod_totp" StringId="DisplayName">TestTOTP</LocalizedString> (NOT WORKING)
      <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaMethod_out-out" StringId="DisplayName">TestOPTOUT</LocalizedString> (NOT WORKING)
   </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>

B2C extension attribute:
      <ClaimType Id="extension_mfaMethod">
        <DisplayName>Please select your preferred Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) method</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>RadioSingleSelect</UserInputType>
        <Restriction>
          <Enumeration Text="Receive a code via Email" Value="email" SelectByDefault="true" />
          <!--<Enumeration Text="Phone" Value="phone" SelectByDefault="false" />-->
          <Enumeration Text="Use an Authenticator App" Value="totp" SelectByDefault="false" />
          <Enumeration Text="Opt out of Multi-Factor Authentication" Value="opt-out" SelectByDefault="false" />
        </Restriction>
      </ClaimType>


Have you had a look at the LocalizedCollection documentation? Perhaps that's what you're looking for.

I was incorrectly using LocalizedStrings when I should have been using LocalizedCollections. I resolved my issue using the below in the localisation policy.
<LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.en">
    <LocalizedCollections>
        <LocalizedCollection ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaMethod"
            TargetCollection="Restriction">
            <Item Text="Email" Value="email" SelectByDefault="true" />
            <Item Text="Authenticator app" Value="totp" />
            <Item Text="Opt out" Value="opt-out" />
        </LocalizedCollection>
    </LocalizedCollections>
    <LocalizedStrings>
        <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="extension_mfaMethod"
            StringId="DisplayName">Please select your preferred Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)
            method</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>

